# cast const Class using dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, constants, dynamic-cast

I want to cast this:

```
class Base 
{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){};
};
class Der : public Base {};

int main()
{
    const Base* base = new Der;
    Der* der = dynamic_cast<Der*>(base); // Error

    return 0;
}
```

What should I do?
I tried to put: `const Der* der = dynamic_cast<Der*>(base);` to mantain the const but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
const Der* der = dynamic_cast<const Der*>(base);
```

`dynamic_cast` doesn't have the ability to remove a `const` qualifier.  You can cast away `const` separately using a `const_cast`, but it's generally a bad idea in most situations.  For that matter, if you catch yourself using `dynamic_cast`, it's usually a sign that there is a better way to do what you are trying to do.  It's not always wrong, but think of it as a warning sign that you are doing things the hard way.

Comment: You need the const twice - once in the type of the variable being assigned to, and once in the `dynamic_cast`.  In the example of what you tried, you only had the first one.

Comment: ok. But just a quesiton under my question.

Why should I keep virtual ~Base(){}; to dynamic_cast doesn't give me an error?

Comment: @okami: You could substitute it with any virtual function, provided you didn't actually need a virtual destructor.  See this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/language_ref/keyword_dynamic_cast.htm "The dynamic_cast operator uses the runtime type information generated from polymorphic classes".  Also, this, on whether you should keep the virtual destructor: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7

Answer (score 4):

```
const Der* der1 = dynamic_cast<const Der*>(base); 

Der* der2 = dynamic_cast<Der*>(const_cast<Base*>(base));
```

while both the above castings work, the second one should be avoided.

Comment: why the second one should be avoided?